# Concise way to destroy user's session in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok, there appears to be few approaches to 'destroying' a user's session and there may be subtleties between them and how the app handles user sessions.

First, why is it most examples don't use `session.delete(:current_user_id)` to delete the `:current_user_id` value (and its hash key!)? A typical example looks like the below (I added deleting `:return_to` since if signing out, why would there by a need to track a return_to value).

```
  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    session[:current_user_id] = nil
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end
```

If the app needs to delete all session variables and values, isn't it safer to simply use `session = nil` or `session.destroy`? This will destroy the hash entirely. It would make sense to keep `current_user_id` in your session hash if your app supports... say tracking of anonymous users ?!?!

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting session to nil you're losing all the information about session (that may also be included except current_user or used by Rails) + you are putting yourself into risk of using a hash method (like #[]) on nil which will raise you exception where you won't expect it.

Comment: Thank you @konole - that makes sense from an exception perspective... two more thoughts maybe worth updating answer on 1) I can simply use `self.current_user = session[:current_user_id] = nil` and 2) `session.delete(:return_to)` really belongs in the method that performs the redirect... can you update if you agree?

Comment: Yes, you can. Though multi assignment shadows the assignment and makes it more unreadable. You could even assign more to nil (C style ftw), though people prefer to get them line by line. ;)

About session.delete(:return_to) - what does it contain?

Comment: Ok, I see you point regarding multi assignment, so let's keep that way. `:return_to` is the page to redirect the user to after authenticating.. `redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to use the rails method [reset_session](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/reset_session). If you want to persist certain portion of the session, I would use something like this in your application controller:

```
  def reset_session_with_persistence(*keys_to_persist)
    persisted_flash = flash
    persisted_keys = keys_to_persist.inject({}) { |keys, key| keys.merge( { key => session[key] } ) }

    reset_session

    persisted_flash.each { |key, value| flash[key] = value }
    keys_to_persist.each { |key_to_persist| session[key_to_persist] = persisted_keys[key_to_persist] }
  end
```

Comment: Using `temp_sess = session.dup` then reseting session followed by `session.replace(temp_sess)` might be easier :-) See here http://brettu.com/rails-daily-ruby-tips-99-use-reset_session-before-authentication/ for an good example!

Comment: Easier, maybe, but less effective. That might take elements that you are deliberately trying to remove.